# Want to create a circuit breaker using vert.x for rabbit MQ

Tags: rabbitmq, vert.x, circuit-breaker

I want to implement circuit breaker using vert.x for rabbit mq. if rabbit mq is down then circuit is open based on the configuration.

I did separate POC for vert.x circuit breaker and also able to connect with Rabbit MQ client . using vert.x .

Now, I want to build circuit breaker if circuit is open then client will not to push messages in  queue , and keep in data base, once circuit is closed then it will start pushing db messages in mq. Please help.

I've use below links for create working poc.

- https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-circuit-breaker/java/
- https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rabbitmq-client/java/

Snippet Used for Circuit Breaker

```
     CircuitBreakerOptions options = new CircuitBreakerOptions()
        .setMaxFailures(0)
        .setTimeout(5000)
        .setMaxRetries(3)
        .setFallbackOnFailure(true);

    CircuitBreaker breaker =
        CircuitBreaker.create("my-circuit-breaker", vertx, options)
        .openHandler(v -> {
          System.out.println("Circuit opened");
        }).closeHandler(v -> {
          System.out.println("Circuit closed");
        }).retryPolicy(retryCount -> retryCount * 100L);

    breaker.executeWithFallback(promise -> {
      vertx.createHttpClient().getNow(8080, "localhost", "/", response -> {
        if (response.statusCode() != 200) {
          promise.fail("HTTP error");
        } else {
          response.exceptionHandler(promise::fail).bodyHandler(buffer -> {
            promise.complete(buffer.toString());
          });
        }
      });
    }, v -> {
      // Executed when the circuit is opened
      return "Hello (fallback)";
    }, ar -> {
      // Do something with the result
      System.out.println("Result: " + ar.result());
    });
  }
```

Snippet Used for RAbbit MQ Client

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    RabbitMQOptions config = new RabbitMQOptions();
    // Each parameter is optional
    // The default parameter with be used if the parameter is not set
    config.setUser("guest");
    config.setPassword("guest");
    config.setHost("localhost");
    config.setPort(5672);
    // config.setVirtualHost("vhost1");
    // config.setConnectionTimeout(6000); // in milliseconds
    config.setRequestedHeartbeat(60); // in seconds
    // config.setHandshakeTimeout(6000); // in milliseconds
    // config.setRequestedChannelMax(5);
    // config.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(500); // in milliseconds
    // config.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
    // vertx.

    RabbitMQClient client = RabbitMQClient.create(vertx, config);
    CircuitBreakerOptions options = new CircuitBreakerOptions().setMaxFailures(0).setTimeout(5000).setMaxRetries(0)
            .setFallbackOnFailure(true);

    CircuitBreaker breaker = CircuitBreaker.create("my-circuit-breaker", vertx, options).openHandler(v -> {
        System.out.println("Circuit opened");
    }).closeHandler(v -> {
        System.out.println("Circuit closed");
    }).retryPolicy(retryCount -> retryCount * 100L);

    
    breaker.executeWithFallback(promise -> {
          vertx.createHttpClient().getNow(8080, "localhost", "/", response -> {
            if (response.statusCode() != 200) {
              promise.fail("HTTP error");
            } else {
              response.exceptionHandler(promise::fail).bodyHandler(buffer -> {
                promise.complete(buffer.toString());
              });
            }
          });
        }, v -> {
          // Executed when the circuit is opened
          return "Hello (fallback)";
        }, ar -> {
          // Do something with the result
          System.out.println("Result: " + ar.result());
        });
    
    client.start(rh -> {

        if (rh.failed()) {
            System.out.println("failed");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i > 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(rh.succeeded());
                System.out.println("client : " + client.isConnected());
                breaker.executeWithFallback(promise -> {
                    if(!client.isConnected()) {
                        promise.fail("MQ client is not connected");
                    }
                },v -> {
                      // Executed when the circuit is opened
                      return "Hello (fallback)";
                    }, ar -> {
                      // Do something with the result
                      System.out.println("Result: " + ar.result());
                    });
                /* RabbitMQClient client2 = RabbitMQClient.create(vertx); */
                JsonObject message = new JsonObject().put("body", "Hello RabbitMQ, from Vert.x !");
                client.basicPublish("eventExchange", "order.created", message, pubResult -> {
                    if (pubResult.succeeded()) {
                        System.out.println("Message published !");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        pubResult.cause().printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Although its working but, circuit open in case rabbit mq down . But its not looks a standard way of ding it with vert.x .

CAn you please suggest of give input how i can implement it.

Comment: You should showcase what you have done so far, then elaborate on what worked and what hadn't.

Comment: Updated details in question itself. Please  help